# File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child raise child_exception

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.8, file-not-found, oserror

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    
import subprocess
import optparse 
def get_arguments():
    parser=optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change mac adress for")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="change mac address")
    return parser.parse_args()
def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("changing you mac address")
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, "  down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, " hw", " ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, " up"])
(options,arguments)=get_arguments()
change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mac_tester.py", line 21, in <module>
    change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
  File "mac_tester.py", line 15, in change_mac
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, "  down"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), make sure your code and errors appear properly (make sure you actually [show the error, completely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146)), and *ask a question*. Just saying "I had an error" is no good.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing space in the names of the executables you are passing to `subprocess.call`, and leading spaces in other arguments. Here's the first line, the other two are similar:

```py
subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, "  down"])
# trailing space here ----^               ^^
# leading spaces here --------------------||
```

This is causing your computer to look for an executable named `ifconfig` , which has a space on the end, and it does not find this executable, so you get an error.

Granted, it might have been easier to find the problem if the error you got included the name of the executable in the error message, for example  `No such file or directory: "ifconfig "`.

Perhaps you think you needed the spaces because you thought that

```py
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
```

would end up attempting to run something like `ifconfigeth0down`? That's not the case: the reason for using `subprocess.call` is to ensure the executable gets the exact arguments you give it, even if the arguments contains spaces or suchlike.

Remove the extra spaces and try again.

Comment: There's a similar problem with the spaces around "down" etc.